# Swift Master-Detail Dismiss Popover

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

In Xcode6 Beta 4, the built in template for the master-detail view no longer dismisses the popover when you click on the detail item in the master's tableview.  Does anyone know how to do that with Swift in Beta 4?

In earlier versions of Xcode6, the template included these 2 methods that controlled the popover, but they are not working for me in Beta 4.

```
func splitViewController(splitController: UISplitViewController, willHideViewController viewController: UIViewController, withBarButtonItem barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem, forPopoverController popoverController: UIPopoverController) {
    barButtonItem.title = "Master" // NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master")
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(barButtonItem, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: nil, action: nil), animated: true)
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController
}

func splitViewController(splitController: UISplitViewController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, invalidatingBarButtonItem barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
    self.masterPopoverController = nil
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will dismiss the popover from the DetailViewController:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    self.masterPopoverController!.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Without more information, this answer is useless. Where does this method go? Where is the self.masterPopoverController property coming from?